# Cycles. Masking shader. How to make objects disappear in plain sight.

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

So I have a scene. I want to slide out a text, for example, as if it was hiding behind an invisible wall. I know that you can achieve this effect with a boolean modifier... but I can't use it in this case. Plus to make it happen with a text you need to convert it into a mesh first - no good.

How to make so that when an object, partially or completely, is inside another object that this makes that part invisible? (The other/masking object is completely invisible all the time, of course)

I sense that it has something to do with a clever Light Path and Mix Shader nodes arrangement.

(Made with a boolean modifier) 
[image]

To achieve this with nodes... Something along the lines of this?
[image]

How it looks in the viewport:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Final:

[image: final]

### Nodes:

For Masking Object - cube in this example just use **Transparent BSDF** with pure white color.

For object being masked - text - use mix between chosen shader (**Diffuse** here) and **Transparent** by **Light Path** > **Transparent Depth**:

[image: node]

> Of course object being masked should be inside masking object.

[image: objects]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty clever solution, nice answer

Comment: Can i have a graduated edge or fall off to the mask?

Comment: You could also do this with render layers using mask layers.