# Occlusion material (holdout) in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I am looking for a way to occlude one cycle´s material against another like when we setup the render passes from the passes property for the scene in a "holdout" mode.

Think 2 spheres over a plane. One sphere overlaps the second one. You can "see through" the overlapped area. If I check "holdout" for one of the spheres, it also cuts out the plane. I only need the ray to instersect (exclude from rays) the intercepting object.

How can I accomplish this? - Thanks.

I am getting close to what I need using a boolean (substract) and a transparent shader...[image]

[image]

Comment: Something like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99305/cycles-masking-shader-how-to-make-objects-disappear-in-plain-sight/99312#99312 ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. Let me see if the masking method works within a sphere. Thanks!! :D

Comment: I've tried it with spheres and it's working fine. Double check if it's exactly what you need.